# What is the current correct way to publish gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

The correct process of publishing gems seems to always be in flux, and it's been a while since I've done it. Is there an up to date set of best practices for bundling ruby libraries into gems and publishing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to learn how to publish gems is to browse the documentation on [guides.rubygems.org](http://guides.rubygems.org).

Here are a few pointers:

- To learn the patterns to bundle a gem, read [this article](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/), or explore a [gem example](https://github.com/qrush/hola).
- The .gemspec file is a descriptor to build your gem. You can read the [detailed specifications here](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/).

Finally, build your gem named `hola` with:

```
gem build hola.gemspec
```

This will create a `hola-0.0.1.gem` file.

To publish your gem to rubygems.org (you’ll need a user account on [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) first):

```
gem push hola-0.0.1.gem
```