# what is requirements to build libraries in ruby?

Tags: rubygems

Hi guys recently i create ruby lib for shodan use in scan ips and search for vulnerabilities in programming languages e.g Ruby, JavaScript or operating systems e.g windows okay but I don’t know how can i put this gem in rubygems.org website and what is requirements to build libraries in ruby

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the current correct way to publish gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104827/what-is-the-current-correct-way-to-publish-gems)